# How are these determinants derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For the intersection of two line segments, how was it know to use the determinants shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-LineIntersection.html)?

I'm trying to determine how it was shown that they could be used to compute the intersection point.

Comment: That seems to be a rather poorly explained, and pretty obscure for whoever who doesn't know it before hand, use of Cramer's Rule. Google it, but it usually requires some knowledge of linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit equation of a line by two points can be written

$$\begin{vmatrix}x&y&1\\x_0&y_0&1\\x_1&y_1&1\end{vmatrix}=ax+by+c=0.$$

You obtain $a,b,c$ as $2\times2$ determinants (cofactors) by developing on the first row.

Then the solution of the $2\times2$ system corresponding to a pair of lines

$$\begin{cases}ax+by+c=0\\a'x+b'y+c'=0\end{cases}$$ is obtained using ratios of $2\times2$ determinants involving $a,b,\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the determinantal form of the equations of the straight lines:

- $\smash[b]{\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x&y&1\end{vmatrix}}$, for the line through $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, which can be written,

$\hspace{7.5em}$expanding along the last row:
$$\begin{vmatrix}y_1&1\\y_2&1\end{vmatrix}x-\begin{vmatrix}x_1&1\\x_2&1\end{vmatrix}y+\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1\\x_2&y_2\end{vmatrix}=0 \tag{1}$$

- Similarly, the line through $(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$  has equation
  $$\begin{vmatrix}y_3&1\\y_4&1\end{vmatrix}x-\begin{vmatrix}x_3&1\\x_4&1\end{vmatrix}y+\begin{vmatrix}x_3&y_3\\x_4&y_4\end{vmatrix}=0\tag{2}$$
  Now apply *Cramer's formulæ* to this linear system.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on the first bullet? I am not sure why that determinant is in the form that it is. I understand how you arrived at the two equations, and now I have a system of two linear equations.

Comment: This determinantal form comes from projective geometry: a point $(x,y)$ in the affine space corresponds to the point $[x:y:1]$ in the projective plane (points in the projective plane are lines through the origin in $\mathbf R^3$) – projective coordinates are defined up to a non-zero constant factor, and three affine points are aligned if the corresponding lines are collinear, whence the equation with a determinant.